Rejection region in hypothesis test using LRT
I have $X_i \sim Bi(1, \theta)$ and want to test $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta \neq \theta_0$ using the LRT test.
I've found that $\lambda = \frac{sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0}L(\theta)}{sup_{\theta \in \Theta}L(\theta)} = \frac{\theta_0^{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}(1-\theta_0)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}}{\bar{X}^{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}(1-\bar{X})^{n-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}}$. Now we know that $U = -2ln(\lambda) \sim \chi^2_1$.
Would the rejection region for this test be $S = \{U \geq \chi^2_{1,1-\alpha/2} \cup U \leq \chi^2_{1,\alpha/2}\}$?

The rejection region should be $\{U > c\}$ where $c$ is the $1-\alpha$ quantile of the chi-squared distribution. The intuition is that larger $U$ values correspond to larger values of $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} L(\theta)$.
The one-sidedness or two-sidedness of the original test is encoded in the likelihood ratio in terms of the choice of $\Theta$ for the alternative. But the threshold for the likelihood ratio statistic is one-sided.
